# how to calculate average and standard deviation of logarithmed numbers

Tags: r, numpy, shell, statistics

I have some 300K probabilities represented as logarithms. I need the average and standard deviation. Is there a better way than exponentiating and calculating the usual way? Solution preferred in Perl / Python / anything I can run from the Linux shell.

Comment: You need the average and sd of the numbers of the original values, not the logged?

Comment: @Reeza yes, exactly.

Comment: Just to clarify these are log with the same base, and not the estimates from logistic regression or something?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: From checking the log and exp identities I don't think there's a simplification for this process :(.